# Translate geo coordinates to pixels in static google maps image using GMap.NET

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I am trying to create a static map from geo location `???,???`
and fetch POI (places of interest) near the location, their geo location is required so I think I need to do a separate query for them and not just set markers for them in the static search.

```
        //transform static map center to pixels
        var center = projection.mercator.FromLatLngToPixel(
            worldPosition.latitude,
            worldPosition.longitude,
            zoom
        );
        //iterate places
        foreach (Place place in map.places)
        {
            //transform place location to pixels
            var point = projection.mercator.FromLatLngToPixel(
                place.location.latitude,
                place.location.longitude,
                zoom
            );
            //calculate pixel position relative to the image center
            var pointRelativeToImage = center - point;

        }
```

However, the results are slightly incorrect, so my question is how I do this right? 
This is the method that calculates the pixel position: (GMaps.Net.Projections.MercatorProjection)

```
  public override GPoint FromLatLngToPixel(double lat, double lng, int zoom)
  {
     GPoint ret = GPoint.Empty;

     lat = Clip(lat, MinLatitude, MaxLatitude);
     lng = Clip(lng, MinLongitude, MaxLongitude);

     double x = (lng + 180) / 360;
     double sinLatitude = Math.Sin(lat * Math.PI / 180);
     double y = 0.5 - Math.Log((1 + sinLatitude) / (1 - sinLatitude)) / (4 * Math.PI);

     GSize s = GetTileMatrixSizePixel(zoom);
     long mapSizeX = s.Width;
     long mapSizeY = s.Height;

     ret.X = (long)Clip(x * mapSizeX + 0.5, 0, mapSizeX - 1);
     ret.Y = (long)Clip(y * mapSizeY + 0.5, 0, mapSizeY - 1);

     return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Hello Samuli, and welcome to the site. This site generally tries to keep questions to-the-point, so I edited down your question.  Feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with my changes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be able to help you, and the code is 5 years old. But I wrote up how to create a heat map using GMap awhile back. Perhaps the code example here can help you? http://blog.ethereal.engineering/2013/01/heatmaps-using-gheat-and-gmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. 
The slightly incorrect results were caused because i was calculating the pixels relative to the center pixel, when i should have calculated them relative to top left pixel. (0,0) pixel in google maps.

Solution:

```
        //translate place to pixels
        var needlePoint = m_mercator.FromLatLngToPixel(needle.latitude,
            needle.longitude,
            zoom);

        //translate map center to pixel
        var haystackPoint = m_mercator.FromLatLngToPixel(haystackCenter.latitude,
            haystackCenter.longitude,
            zoom);

        //calculate the top left pixel
        var haystackCorner = new Point(haystackPoint.x-(imageSize.x/2),
            haystackPoint.y-(imageSize.y/2));

        //translate the pixel to local space relative to the map
        var point = new Point(needlePoint.x - haystackCorner.x,
            needlePoint.y - haystackCorner.y);
```

This works assuming the 0,0 pixel on the image is on the top left corner, apparently the image API i was using had 0,0 pixel on the bottom left corner.